# How can I extract and name all of these data frames from this list in R?

Tags: r

How I can get these data frames out of this unholy list? Using an 'apply' function, I would also like to assign each a variable if possible.

```
List of 452
 $ :'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X[[i]]: int [1:11] 39 12 51 6 14 3 5 1 5 5 ...
  ..$ time  : chr [1:11] "2018-08-29T19:00:00-06:00" "2018-08-30T11:00:00-06:00" "2018-08-30T12:00:00-06:00" "2018-08-30T13:00:00-06:00" ...
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X[[i]]: int [1:4] 2 1 8 25
  ..$ time  : chr [1:4] "2018-08-28T13:00:00-06:00" "2018-08-28T23:00:00-06:00" "2018-08-29T21:00:00-06:00" "2018-08-29T22:00:00-06:00"
```

Comment: Check out `?setNames` to find out how to assign names to elements of a list, and then check out `list2env` to check out how to instantiate these dataframes in the global environment (if this is really what you want).

Comment: Typically, "best practice" would be considered to keep them in a list, but make it a named list, using `setNames`, as mentioned above, or if each data frame is structured the same you could use `dplyr::bind_rows()` to combine them into a single data frame with a column taken from the list names as an ID column. Both of those options will be better to work with than 452 separate variables in your workspace.